# Why is $|z_1| < 1$ and $|z_2| > 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Here are the values of $z_1$ and $z_2$

$$z_1 = \frac{-i + i \sqrt{1-r^2}}{r}$$

$$z_2 = \frac{-i - i \sqrt{1-r^2}}{r}$$

Where $0 < r < 1.$

Then, the writer said , then  we have $|z_1| < 1$ and $|z_2|>1$ but I calculated $|z_1|$ and $|z_2|$ and I found them equals $$\frac{1 + 2 \sqrt{1 - r^2} + (1-r^2)}{r^2}$$ So, I do not know why the author said this actually. Here is the link for the question that contains this claim [Several questions on calculating $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\mathrm{d} \theta}{1+r\sin \theta}$ via contours](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4515934/several-questions-on-calculating-int-02-pi-frac-mathrmd-theta1r-sin) , could anyone clarify this to me please? and sorry if this was a very trivial question.

**EDIT:**

I do not see why $|z_1|$ looks like this. Mine is just $\sqrt{\frac{(-1)^2}{r^2} + (\frac{\sqrt{-1 + r^2}}{r})^2} = 1$

Can someone show me the detailed calculations please?

Comment: Include your calculations, each and every step made. Otherwise no one can say what errors you made.

Comment: The "equals" result you showed is neither $\lvert z_1\rvert$ nor $\lvert z_2\rvert.$ It is $\lvert z_2^2\rvert.$ As noted in the previous comment, it is impossible to know what you did wrong without seeing what you did, but a guess is that you also tried to compute $\lvert z_1^2\rvert$ and made a sign error.

Comment: @DavidK I will edit my question in a few minutes after taking the first answer below advice (or after factorizing again according to your comment there)

Comment: Both the given $z_1$ and $z_2$ are purely imaginary with zero real part. They are neither $\dfrac{-1\pm i\sqrt{1-r^2}}{r}$ nor $\dfrac{-i\pm \sqrt{1-r^2}}{r}$, as you apparently thought when calculating their absolute values.

Comment: I think you have sth incorrect under your square root in the second expression @peterwhy

Comment: Agree that both of my expressions are incorrect, so I said "they are neither ... nor...

Comment: @peterwhy what you said just return me to the calculations in my question without the edit .... how this will lead to what is claimed by the author about the absolute values of $z_1$ and $z_2$

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;z_1 \cdot z_2 = 1\,$ so $\,|z_1| \cdot |z_2| = 1\,$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $|z_1|=\frac {1-\sqrt {1-r^{2}}} r$ and $|z_2|=\frac {1+\sqrt {1-r^{2}}} r$. Note that $1-r+\sqrt {1-r^{2}} >0$ (which gives $|z_2|>1$) and $\sqrt {1-r} <1<\sqrt {1+r} $ (so $(1-r)<\sqrt {(1-r)(1+r)}=\sqrt {1-r^{2}}$, which gives $|z_1| <1$).

Comment: I do not see why $|z_1|$ looks like this. Mine is just $\sqrt{\frac{(-1)^2}{r^2} + (\frac{\sqrt{-1 + r^2}}{r})^2}$

Comment: I saw your point just now

Comment: I managed to understand, using your first inequality, how $|z_1| < 1.$ But I do not know how to use your second inequality to understand that $|z_2| > 1, $ could you elaborate please?

Comment: I think $|z_2|> 1$ is clear as the numerator is always greater than 1 and the denominator is always less than 1, right? so we do not need your second inequality, right?

Comment: Sure.  I have added some details. @Brain

Comment: @Brain Yes. $|z_2| >1$ is the easy part.

Comment: @Brain I multiplied both sides of $\sqrt {1-r} <\sqrt {1+r}$ by $\sqrt {1-r}$.

Comment: Yeah I realized that,  that is why I deleted my comment quickly :)